# Stream logs to elastic using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to enable the Stream to Amazon Elasticsearch Service from Cloudwatch to Elasticsearch.

[image]

I'm familiar with how to do that manually, I'm looking for a way to achieve that by running aws cli commands.

assuming Elasticsearch is already configured, is there any way to automate the process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

If you are using cloudformation, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58558891/9931092).

---

Many thanks to @Adiii that pointed me in the right direction,Find bellow the end to end solution for this issue.

The solution Include the following parts :

- create-lambda-role
- grant-permissions-to-lambda-role
- create-lambda
- grant-cloudwatch-permission-to-execute-lambda
- add-subscription-to-cloudwatch-log-group

I assume that the lambda function is already packaged and accessible.
You can find the lambda function [here](https://github.com/AmitBaranes/Stream-to-ElasticSearch/blob/master/LogsToElasticsearch.zip).

Update `var endpoint = ${Elasticsearch_Endpoint};` in index.js with your Elasticseatch url e.g - `search-xxx-yyyy.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com;`.

Manually steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html).

**1. create-lambda-role**

First, we need to create the role that the lambda function use, later we will attach relevant policies to that role.

```
    cat > lambda-policy.json << EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
} 
EOF

    aws iam create-role \
    --role-name ${ROLE_NAME} \
    --assume-role-policy-document file://lambda-policy.json \
    --profile ${PROFILE} \
    >/dev/null
```

**2. grant-permissions-to-lambda-role**

Attach relevant policies to lambda role.

```
 cat > lambda-to-es-via-vpc-policy.json << EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1569580358341",
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:domain/${ES_DOMAIN}/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1569580707924",
      "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

    aws iam put-role-policy \
    --role-name ${ROLE_NAME} \
    --policy-name lambda-to-es-via-vpc-policy \
    --policy-document file://lambda-to-es-via-vpc-policy.json \
    --profile ${PROFILE} \
    >/dev/null
```

**3. create-lambda**

```
aws lambda create-function \
    --function-name ${LAMBDA_NAME} \
    --runtime nodejs8.10 \
    --role arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${ROLE_NAME} \
    --handler ${LAMBDA_NAME}.handler \
    --zip-file fileb://${LAMBDA_NAME}.zip \
    --timeout 30 \
    --vpc-config SubnetIds=${SUBNET_IDS},SecurityGroupIds=${SECURITY_GROUP_IDS} \
    --profile ${PROFILE} \
    >/dev/null
```

**4. grant-cloudwatch-permission-to-execute-lambda**

Grants an AWS service or another account permission to use a function.

```
aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name "${LAMBDA_NAME}" \
--statement-id "${LAMBDA_NAME}" \
--principal "logs.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com" \
--action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
--source-arn "arn:aws:logs:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:log-group:/aws/eks/${EKS_CLUSTER}/cluster:*" \
--source-account ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID} \
--profile ${PROFILE} \
>/dev/null
```

**5. add-subscription-to-cloudwatch-log-group**

Creates or updates a subscription filter and associates it with the specified log group. Subscription filters allow you to subscribe to a real-time stream of log events, and have them delivered to a specific destination.

```
  aws logs put-subscription-filter \
   --log-group-name  "/aws/eks/${EKS_CLUSTER}/cluster" \
   --filter-name "Common Log Format" \
   --filter-pattern "[host, ident, authuser, date, request, status, bytes]" \
   --destination-arn  arn:aws:lambda:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:function:${LAMBDA_NAME} \
   --profile ${PROFILE} \
   >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scene Stream to Amazon Elasticsearch service create new lambda and then it pushes the log to Lambda then ELK.

**destination arn**

> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the Kinesis stream, Kinesis Data
>   Firehose stream, or Lambda function you want to use as the destination
>   of the subscription feed.

So here is the way to push to AWS lambda and Lambda will automatically push these stream to ELK.

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name log_group_name --filter-pattern "" --filter-name filter_name_demo   --destination-arn arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:***********:function:your_lambda_name
```

[AmazonCloudWatch-logs-Subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but the put-subscription-filter its the end of the process. I'm looking for a script that will automate it end to end ( Lambda creation,roles,policies,stream )

Comment: You are supposed to push existing stream, while lambda creation is possible