# stream logs to elastic using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

Cloudtrail default logs can be streamed to elasticsearch domain as shown in this image. How do I achieve this using cloudformation template?

[image]

Comment: Your question shows no attempt to find a solution.

Comment: I wrote a very detailed answer about how to achieve that by aws cli.i couldn't find any documentation about cloud formation.Please let me know if you succeeded to achieve that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062415/enable-stream-to-amazon-elasticsearch-service-via-aws-cli

Comment: @AmitBaranes is it possible to use a cloudformation template for all the steps mentioned in that post?

Comment: Well, I've tried to do that by cloudformation but the customer rather uses the aws cli, So I quit it.   I'll try to do that by cloudformation this weekend.

Comment: Unfortunately the `AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter` doesn't currently support Elasticsearch as a destination, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html.

Comment: @jogold You need to create lambda and add a subscription from cloudwatch to that lamda. take a look at my answer.

Comment: Here is a medium article explaining the purpose of the template. https://medium.com/@shantanuo/cloudfromation-template-for-visualising-aws-cloudtrail-logs-ae700ac908bb?sk=c1abb69aa66bf08cdd640696de317194

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

If you are using aws-cli, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062415/stream-logs-to-elastic-using-aws-cli).

---

Well, after a few hours of exploring and reading a lot of documentation I finally succeeded to create this template.

Designer Overview :

[image]

In order to enable the stream logs to elasticsearch we need to create the following resources:

1. The lambda function will forward the logs from cloudwatch log group to Elasticsearch.
2. Relevant IAM Role to get logs from cloudwatch and insert to Elasticsearch.
3. [Lambda permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) - `The AWS::Lambda::Permission resource grants an AWS service or another account permission to use a function` to allow the cloudwatch log group to trigger the lambda.
4. [Subscription Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html)  - `The AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter resource specifies a subscription filter and associates it with the specified log group. Subscription filters allow you to subscribe to a real-time stream of log events and have them delivered to a specific destination.`

Template usage:

1. Download LogsToElasticsearch.zip from my [Github page](https://github.com/AmitBaranes/Stream-to-ElasticSearch/blob/master/LogsToElasticsearch.zip).
2. Update `var endpoint = '${Elasticsearch_Endpoint}';` in index.js with your Elasticseatch url e.g - `'search-xxx-yyyy.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com';`.
3. Copy the zip file to s3 bucket which will be used in the template (LambdaArtifactBucketName).
4. Fill relevant Parameters - you can find descriptions to each resource.

Template YAML:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Enable logs to elasticsearch
Parameters:
  ElasticsearchDomainName:
    Description: Name of the Elasticsearch domain that you want to insert logs to
    Type: String
    Default: amitb-elastic-domain
  CloudwatchLogGroup:
    Description: Name of the log group you want to subscribe
    Type: String
    Default: /aws/eks/amitb-project/cluster
  LambdaName:
    Description: Name of the lambda function
    Type: String
    Default: amitb-cloudwatch-logs
  LambdaRole:
    Description: Name of the role used by the lambda function
    Type: String
    Default: amit-cloudwatch-logs-role
  LambdaArtifactBucketName:
    Description: The bucket where the lambda function located
    Type: String
    Default: amit-bucket
  LambdaArtifactName:
    Description: The name of the lambda zipped file
    Type: String
    Default: LogsToElasticsearch.zip
  VPC:
    Description: Choose which VPC the Lambda-functions should be deployed to
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
    Default: vpc-1111111
  Subnets:
    Description: Choose which subnets the Lambda-functions should be deployed to
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Default: 'subnet-123456789,subnet-123456456,subnet-123456741'
  SecurityGroup:
    Description: Select the Security Group to use for the Lambda-functions
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>'
    Default: 'sg-2222222,sg-12345678'
Resources:
  ExampleInvokePermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    DependsOn: ExampleLambdaFunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        'Fn::GetAtt':
          - ExampleLambdaFunction
          - Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: !Sub 'logs.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
      SourceArn: !Sub >-
        arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:${CloudwatchLogGroup}:*
      SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Ref LambdaRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: lambda-to-es-via-vpc-policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'es:*'
                Resource:
                  - !Sub >-
                    arn:aws:es:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:domain/${ElasticsearchDomainName}
        - PolicyName: logs-and-ec2-permissions
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
                  - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
                  - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: '*'
  ExampleLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    DependsOn: LambdaExecutionRole
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref LambdaArtifactBucketName
        S3Key: !Ref LambdaArtifactName
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaName
      Handler: !Sub '${LambdaName}.handler'
      Role:
        'Fn::GetAtt':
          - LambdaExecutionRole
          - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Timeout: '300'
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets
      MemorySize: 512
  SubscriptionFilter:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter'
    DependsOn: ExampleInvokePermission
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Ref CloudwatchLogGroup
      FilterPattern: '[host, ident, authuser, date, request, status, bytes]'
      DestinationArn:
        'Fn::GetAtt':
          - ExampleLambdaFunction
          - Arn
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Cloudwatch log:
[image]

Hope you find it helpfull.

**Update 02/09/2020:**

node.js 8.10 is now deprecated, you should use node.js 10 or 12.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html

[image]

Comment: everything is successfully installed through template, but elastic is not populated. This is lambda error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:15:53)

Comment: The lambda function does not install a trigger? How will the function invoke? The error mentioned above is shown when I run the function manually.

Comment: It does install the trigger, take a look at the first result image I share. The function invoke when new data stream to cloudwatch, and then the cloudwatch group log triggers the lambda with the relevant event, which is the new log.

Comment: The reason you get this error: `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at exports.handler` is because the lambda function expects to get data as the input. when you run the lambda manually, there is no input (or wrong input)

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Everything is working as expected. I did not check correctly. The problem was that I was using domain with "https" part in step 2 of updating var endpoint.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to merge this template with my template? https://datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/cftemplates/audit_trail.yaml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201441/discussion-between-amit-baranes-and-shantanuo).

Comment: @AmitBaranes does this architecture has any issue with amount of logs streaming through cloudwatch log groups. In terms concurrent executions, lambda can handle certain requests per second. Any tips how to avoid that?

Comment: This architecture is just a way to implement stream to elasticsearch using cloud formation, as much as I've been tested this solution, no issues were found even if there way many requests per second. in case you face any specific issue, I would be happy to help you solve it.