# pause the template execution for a few minutes

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template that works correctly. It initiates an elastic server along with cloud-trail.

datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/cftemplates/audit_trail.yaml

I have to wait for 10 minute to get the endpoint. The endpoint is used in Lambda function that is part of another template.

[stream logs to elastic using cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425218/stream-logs-to-elastic-using-cloudformation-template)

Is there WaitCondition in cloudformaton that I can use before joining these 2 templates?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitcondition.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a `WaitCondition` that uses properties like `Count`, `Handle`, `Timeout`.

More info about the same is [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitcondition.html)

**Example Code**

Declare an `AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle resource in the stack's template

```
"myWaitHandle" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle",
     "Properties" : {
     }
}
```